# C# Read file, split at ; write in array

Tags: c#, arrays, file

so I have a file like this:

```
1;2;5
1;3;3
1;4;3
1;5;1
1;6;0
```

and I want every number as easy accassible as possibe
so I thought multi dimentional array

that's the idea so far:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Hisfantor\Desktop\transport.txt");
            

            int count = 0;
            string linee;
            string line;
            string[] extract;

            while ((linee = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                count++;
            }
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);

            double[,] destinations = new double[(int)count, 3];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                line = file.ReadLine();
                extract = line.Split(';');
                destinations[i, 1] = Convert.ToDouble(extract[0]);
                destinations[i, 2] = Convert.ToDouble(extract[1]);
                destinations[i, 3] = Convert.ToDouble(extract[2]);

                listBox1.Items.Add(destinations[i, 1]);

            } 

            file.Close();
```

I tried different things, but never get anything in the listbox(just for testing)

Comment: You reading the Stream to end in the first loop. Use something the is not a `double[,]` to store your data (something you can `Add()` to).

Comment: Wonder if co-pilot could have turned the title into code.  https://copilot.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Hisfantor\Desktop\transport.txt");
        
int count = 0;
string line;
string[] extract;

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    extract = line.Split(';');
    var lineValue = new LineValue()
    {
        Col1 = Convert.ToDouble(extract[0]),
        Col2 = Convert.ToDouble(extract[1]),
        Col3 = Convert.ToDouble(extract[2]),
    };

    listBox1.Items.Add(lineValue);     
    count++;
}

textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(count);

public class LineValue
{
    public double Col1 { get; set; }
    public double Col2 { get; set; }
    public double Col3 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{Col1};{Col2};{Col3}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *jagged* array, i.e. array of array `double[][]` instead of 2D one (`double[,]`). Then you can *query* the file with a help of *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ... 

 double[][] destinations = File
   .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Hisfantor\Desktop\transport.txt")
   .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
   .Select(line => line
      .Split(';')
      .Select(item => double.Parse(item))
      .ToArray())
   .ToArray();

 foreach (var array in destinations)
   listBox1.Items.Add(array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it.

```
class Item
{
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
}

string line;
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] tokens = line.Split(';');
        if (tokens.Length == 3)
        {
            int value;
            Item item = new Item();
            item.Value1 = int.TryParse(tokens[0], out value) ? value : 0;
            item.Value2 = int.TryParse(tokens[1], out value) ? value : 0;
            item.Value3 = int.TryParse(tokens[2], out value) ? value : 0;
            items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This code reads a line at a time and populates a list of `Item`s as it reads them. It includes error checking to avoid unexpected exceptions due to invalid inputs.

Also, you should wrap `StreamReader` in a `using` block to ensure it cleans up in a timely manner, even if an exception exits your method prematurely.